# Looking for a good GUI library for C

Tags: c, user-interface

As the title says, I am looking for a good library for the C Programming Language.

The GUI library should be really popular. I'd also appreciate if there are popular forums on the Internet where I can ask professionals for help. And I definitively need a good book about the library. If it's possible it should be cross-platform but I can live without that... I guess ;)

The only library I know for C so far is GTK. It sounded really well to me but neither did I find any good book (I've actually seen only one book about GTK and I don't know if it's good or bad cause nobody posted a review) nor did I see anyone using it except 2 guys on You-tube with their impressing amount of 2 videos! >.< .

The really important thing for me is that it should be popular... I don't want to sit here, learn how to use this library and in a year or two nobody uses it any more.

I hope you guys can help me finding a library :)

Comment: it's c++ but have a look at http://www.wxwidgets.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK+ is hugely popular and is used extensively. It's the best choice if you want cross-platform GUI development in C alone. There are plenty of books around, though they're a bit outdated (but most of it still applies). You can find up to date tutorials and full API documentation at the GNOME project website.

Answer (score 1):

GTK is the most popular GUI library in C you can find.
Have you tried [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_283155_ln?rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Agtk&keywords=gtk&ie=UTF8&qid=1362847298&scn=283155&h=fbd69ebdb1a0eee489c0e7a1c90220970850a709)? There're plenty of books. It's hard to believe that all of them are bad.

Comment: Yeah I looked like 20 times for GTk books there but found only one book about it.

Comment: Check out the amazon link I gave above, which lists other books as well.